# Не отображаются заданные стили, логотип и шрифт на PHP-сайте

Tags: php, вёрстка

Здравствуйте.
Создал html-сайт, затем стал переносить его на PHP и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при подключении файла header.php к php-файлу, который лежит по другому, нежели index.php, пути, логотип и скачанные шрифты в хедере не работают.
Я неправильно задаю формат пути?
Сайт размещён на локальном сервере DENWER.
Спасибо!

Comment: Указывайте полный путь до ресурсов ( `http://my.site/res/style.css` ), а не относительный ( `res/style.css` ). Если предполагается, что сайт будет перемешаться с домена на домен, то формируйте пути динамически при помощи php.

Comment: Т.е. лучше с денвера сайт залить на хостинг?

Comment: Денвер выкиньте и забудьте, так как он давно устарел и не обновляется! Используйте другой WAMP для разработки, который поддерживается и обновляется в настоящем времени. А по путям. Заводите константу в которой прописываете baseurl сайта и используете эту константу в формировании всех адресов на сайте. Тогда при переезде с локалхоста на рабочий сервер, вам нужно буде сменить ее и все адреса на сайте поменяются.

Comment: Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, актуальный WAMP.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как задать эту самую константу? Я просто новичок, только начал изучение. Спасибо)

Comment: Сейчас моден "Open server" https://ospanel.io/
А по поводу путей, рекомендую почитать про полный и относительные пути, ознакомится с такими штуками как "../" и "./". А потом отдельно потренироваться подключать файлы в папках разных уровней вложенности.

Comment: @Visman это чем же относительные пути плохи? Как раз для подключения статики очень даже подходят, и домен тут явно лишний

Comment: @DaemonHK, и при установке в папку сайта по каким-то причинам тоже хороши?

Comment: @Visman, ну, проблемы могут наблюдаться только если на поддомен ставить сайт